# Using CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql-server, cross-apply

I have table `Car` with car `ID`'s (`smallint`), and another table with events related with each car.

Now I want to get latest event for cars selected by certain criteria, but this does not seem to work.

When I have query like this to get the latest event for every car it works ok:

```
SELECT * FROM [dvm_data].[dbo].[Car] CD 
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dvm_data].[dbo].[CarData] WHERE CarIndex = CD.ID) MD
```

On the other hand, when I try to limit cars using `WHERE` in first `SELECT`, it no longer works:

```
SELECT * FROM [dvm_data].[dbo].[Car] WHERE ID > 100 CD 
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dvm_data].[dbo].[CarData] WHERE CarIndex = CD.ID) MD
```

In this case I get error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'CD'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near 'MD'.

The first query in itself works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM [dvm_data].[dbo].[Car] WHERE ID > 100
```

What I am missing here? Usually examples using `CROSS APPLY` do not have `WHERE` in the first SELECT query, does this mean something?

Another thing, what if I want to use `DISTINCT` in first query, to find cars that had certain type of event, and then finding latest event for these cars. It would be something like this, but also this does not work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM [dvm_data].[dbo].[CarData] WHERE EventID = 32 CD 
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dvm_data].[dbo].[CarData] WHERE CarIndex = CD.ID) MD
```

I suppose this should be very easy, but currently I am missing something...

Comment: Your subquery has a problem. You have top 1 but there is no order by. That means you have no way of knowing which row you will get. And using * in your column list is bad practice. You should be explicit with your column names and only return the rows you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your where clause is on the wrong position! try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM [dvm_data].[dbo].[Car] CD 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM [dvm_data].[dbo].[CarData] 
    WHERE CarIndex = CD.ID
) MD
WHERE CD.ID > 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have placed `where` clause at wrong place,

```
SELECT * FROM [dvm_data].[dbo].[Car] CD 
CROSS APPLY 
(
  SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dvm_data].[dbo].[CarData] WHERE CarIndex = CD.ID
) MD
WHERE ID > 100
```

For better understanding about syntax refer [Select statement in Sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms189499.aspx)