# SQL Server, cross-apply, and DISTINCT

Tags: sql-server, distinct, cross-apply

I had earlier problem with CROSS APPLY, which solved nicely ([Using CROSS APPLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116291/using-cross-apply/)).

Here is another part. I want to get one newest CarData row (all columns!) for all those cars which have new line within 24 hours.
As I assume, first SELECT should get distinct CarIndexes for all those cars which have updated events within 24 hours, and second SELECT gives newest row.
Anyhow I dont know where to put DISTINCT word properly, now I just get the list of CarIndexes instead of CarData rows using this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CD.CarIndex FROM [dvm_data].[dbo].[CarData] CD 
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dvm_data].[dbo].[CarData] WHERE CarIndex = CD.CarIndex ORDER BY ID DESC) MD
WHERE CD.DatetimeOccurred > (GETDATE()-1)
```

So, how to make DISTINCT and whole rows work?

Comment: `distinct *` instead of  `DISTINCT CD.CarIndex`?

Comment: distinct * is not working, return huge amount of rows. Another question is solved, but this is different one.

Comment: You are not selecting the fields you needed, try SELECT DISTINCT CD.CarIndex, MD.* From [dvm_data].[dbo].[CarData] CD ......

Comment: Suggestion by XtremeBytes works neither. The problem is, that I want to pass those DISTINCT car ID's to "SELECT TOP 1 * ...." clause, so maybe this whole query is constructed in wrong way. But I cannot decipher how to make it right... :/